# Sitecore: DMS 7.1 Analytics is disabled

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-dms, sitecore7.1

I am trying to get Sitecore DMS 7.1 working.  I followed the instructions on the sitecore support pages.  I triple checked all the steps referred to on this website.

https://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/08/Troubleshooting-Analytics-is-Disabled-with-the-Sitecore-Customer-Engagement-Platform.aspx#comments

I have looked in the log file and i am getting.

```
3112 10:20:35 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpException
Message: Online Marketing Suite is not enabled
Source: mscorlib

Server stack trace: 
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Reports.ReportDataHandler.AssertState(HttpContext context)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Reports.ReportDataHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed, MessageData& msgData)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Reports.ReportDataHandler.RequestProcessor.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Reports.ReportDataHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
```

Help.  We have other sitecore sites and I was able to get it working on sitecore 7 platform.

Comment: Do you have the Sitecore DMS/analytics license on your instance?

Comment: It was a license issue or lack there of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the logic that is causing the error to be thrown:

```csharp
public static bool Enabled
{
    get
    {
        if (Settings.GetBoolSetting("Analytics.Enabled", false))
            return Sitecore.SecurityModel.License.License.HasModule("Sitecore.OMS");
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

So you can see that there are 2 criteria that need to be met.

First, the "Analytics.Enabled" setting in the analytics config file need to be set to true. It should look like the following.

```xml
<!--
     ANALYTICS ENABLED
     Determines whether analytics is enabled or not.
     Default: true  
-->
<setting name="Analytics.Enabled" value="true" />
```

Second, your license needs to include DMS (It's refers to it as "OMS" internally).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Context.Site.EnableAnalytics)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Please, elaborate more on your answers